# Best practices to purge millions of data in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to 1 billion data which 10 years before records from a table tblmail , for that I have created the below procedure.
I am doing through batch size.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PURGE_Data AS 
 batch_size INTEGER := 1000;
 pvc_procedure_name        CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'Purge_data';
 pvc_info_message_num      CONSTANT NUMBER := 1;
 pvc_error_message_type    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(5) := 'ERROR';
v_message    schema_mc.db_msg_log.message%TYPE;
v_msg_num    schema_mc.db_msg_log.msg_num%TYPE;
/*
    Purpose: Provide stored procedures to be used to purge unwanted archives.
*/
BEGIN
Delete from tblmail where createdate_dts < (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '10' YEAR) and ROWNUM <= batch_size;
COMMIT;      
EXCEPTION  
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
                     ROLLBACK;
                     v_msg_num := SQLCODE;
                     v_message := 'Error deleting from tblmail table';
                     INSERT INTO error_log
                             (date, num, type, source, mail)
                         VALUES              
                             (systimestamp, v_msg_num, pvc_error_message_type,pvc_procedure_name, v_message);
                     COMMIT;      
END;
```

Do I need to use bulk collect and delete? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: A single delete operation would be faster than batches, but your database might not be configured to allow a one-off deletion of a billion records. How many rows are you keeping? Have you talked to your DBA about this?

Answer (score 0):

As always in computing it depends. Provided that you have an index on createdate_dts your procedure should work, but how do you know when to stop calling it? I tend to use a loop:

```
loop
  delete /*+ first_rows */ from tblmail where createdate_dts <
    (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '10' YEAR) and ROWNUM <= batch_size;
  v_rows := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  commit;
  exit when v_rows = 0;
end loop;
```

You could also return the number of deleted records if you want to keep the loop outside of the procedure. Without an index on createdate_dts it may be cheaper to collect the primary keys for the rows to delete in one pass first and then loop over them, deleting batch size records per commit with bulk collect or something. However, when possible it is always nice to use a simple solution! You may want to experiment a bit in order to find the best batch size.